# SQL, PHP, Prepared Statement

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a prepared statement to populate my table from PHP.

No errors are being thrown however, the data is not entering the table. Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Parks VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,Now(),?,?,?, 0, 0, 0)");
    if ($stmt === FALSE) {
    die ("Mysql Error: " . $mysqli->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss', $name, $theme, $size, $mountains, $hills, $river, $lake, $island, $setofislands, $ocean, $waterfalls, $file, $image, $description, $author,$cs);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
```

Thanks in advance.

**Data Types:**

- ID (Int(autoincrement))
- Name (varchar(255))
- Theme (varchar(255))
- Size (varchar(255))
- Mountains (varchar(255))
- Hills (varchar(255))
- Rivers (varchar(255))
- Lake (varchar(255))
- Island (varchar(255))
- Setofislands (varchar(255))
- Ocean (varchar(255))
- Waterfall (varchar(255))
- File (varchar(255))
- Image (varchar(255))
- DateUploaded (date)
- Description(varchar(255))
- Author (varchar(255))
- CS(varchar(2000))
- Download(int(255))
- Rating(double)
- FileSize(BigInt(20)

(total 21)

Note: I have tried prepared statements on a test database, which just had one column and that worked...

Comment: try dropping bind_param() and putting the data in the execute()

Comment: you need to check $mysqli->error after every interaction with database

Comment: @user1662290 can you post error here

Comment: There isn't an error. 
The data just isn't showing up in the database.

Comment: Does the number of bound parameters match up with the number of `?`? I'm counting one extra parameter being bound (no idea if PHP would silently fail in a situation like that).

Comment: @Kitsune: `ssss...` are just the types of the variables; see http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php - @user1662290: how is the table defined?

Comment: Hi, It's already been suggested there was more parameters than '?' however, after adding an extra '?' PHP threw an error stating that there was too many '?' I've updated the post showing the variable types

I've also set it to return the data before putting it into the queyr to ensure that data exists in the variables. All of the variables contain data...

Comment: Please follow the advice of checking errors yourself before going any futher or you'll waste a lot of time just guessing—mysqli doesn't through errors by itself!

Comment: The big issue here is that PHP is not throwing any areas it's failing silently.
There are sufficient placeholders to data being entered
and all of the data being entered contain data
Neither PHP nor SQL returns any errors but data is not being entered into the table.

Comment: I'm not sure you really understand how to check for errors (posted code suggest you don't). It's not enough to have `if ($stmt === FALSE)` on top of the code. You need to check the return value of **all** mysqli function calls!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the suggestion.
I have implemented error calls throughout the application checking both mysqli and stmt for errors every other line.
However, there is still no error being returned from any error call...

Answer (score 0):

After a series of trial and error I was able to resolve the issue.

It seemed that:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssi', etc
$stmt->exceute();
```

Was needed and that listing out the column names:

```
Insert into Parks (name, description) Values (?, ?)
```

were the changes needed to make it work.
To confirm, it now all works, thanks for everyones support on this! :)

Comment: 1. you don't need that listing if your values match all the fields in the table. 2. Whatever way, mysql would throw an error on a case like this, and you've been told to check for errors already.